# ggplot size aesthetic with smaller dots

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, aesthetics

This is probably a simple question, but I don't know the answer off the top of my head. Is it possible to rescale the dots in ggplot, without ruining your size aesthetic?

Basically, let's say I have the following:

```
data <- data.frame(size=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x=1:5, y=1:5, color=factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1)))
cols <- unique(data$color)
names(cols) <- c("group 1", "group 2")
sols <- unique(data$size)
names(sols) <- c("group 1", "group 2")
```

I may plot this as:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x, y=y, size=size, color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete("Dot", labels=names(cols)) +
  scale_size_continuous("Dot", breaks=sols)
```

which shows dots like:

[image]

This looks great, but let's say now I have 1000 observations of my data instead of just 5. All of a sudden, my plot is heavily congested with dots since group2 dots are so big. How do I rescale the dots to make them more appropriately sized so that I can fit more points without dots overlapping? I have considered geom_density but it doesn't really fit my purposes here and I would prefer a scatterplot visualization.

My goal is some function that rescales my points such that the dots in general are just smaller than they are now with the appropriate proportion of the sizing. To keep things more reasonable, once I have that, I will be doing a log-transform of the size variable to make things better proportioned (particularly, since any overall rescaling of the points will probably lead to the smaller points being near invisible small). If there is any better way to do this, I'm all ears! Thanks guys.

Comment: if you have several points, you could use alpha

Comment: yah; ive tried playing with alpha; doesnt quite do enough that I was hoping for :( Thanks for the suggestion though! Particularly, one of the groups with a large size happens to also have a lot of dots, so when I view in the current size spec, the entire background is basically the color of the dots for the largest group, regardless of the alpha).

Comment: What about hexbins ?  (`geom_hex()`)

Comment: I don't think hexbins allows you to weight points within a bin?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Can use the `scale_size()` function to map directly to size values as follows (using the initial example):

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x, y=y, size=size, color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete("Dot", values=cols) +
  scale_size_continuous("Dot", breaks=sols) +
  scale_size(range=c(0.5, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes and for may use case, scale_size_area() was the right choice. It made a huge difference in how my squares (shape = 22) were being represented.